# ¿Cómo puedo crear un panel para cargar datos en Java Swing?

Tags: java, jframe

Explico mi situación, tengo una clase principal `Ventana_GestionarLegajos` con una tabla de familiares que posee un botón INGRESAR FAMILIAR, necesito que se abra un pequeño formulario donde el usuario ingrese algunos datos y al presionar `CONFIRMAR`, poder contar con todos los datos para gestionarlos.

En estos momentos tengo esto:

[image: Interfaz actual del sistema]

```
private void ingresarFamiliarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    String [] array ={"","","",""};
    JTextField nombre = new JTextField();
    JTextField documento = new JTextField();
    JTextField fecha_nacimiento = new JTextField();
    JTextField parentesco = new JTextField();
    Object[] message = {
        "Nombre:", nombre,
        "Documento:", documento,
        "Fecha de Nacimiento:", fecha_nacimiento,
        "Parentesco:", parentesco,
    };
    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Llena el formulario", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    array[0]=nombre.getText();
    array[1]=documento.getText();
    array[2]=fecha_nacimiento.getText();
    array[3]=parentesco.getText();}
}
```

Pero me gustaría que la inserción se realice desde un `JFrame` que ya tengo creado, la clase `Ventana_NuevoFamiliar`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no sé como obtener los datos desde la clase madre. En el ejemplo anterior, lo hacía de manera sencilla con un *get(text)* porque estaba dentro de la misma clase. Pero con dos clases no puedo hacer eso. No sé como continuar el código.

```
private void ingresarFamiliarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    Ventana_NuevoFamiliar v = new Ventana_NuevoFamiliar();
    v.setVisible(true);    
}
```

Como podría continuar el código?

Comment: Crea un método que te devuelva un pojo y tienes referencia de la clase Hija dentro de la clase padre, entonces al terminar el JFrame, el objeto tendrá esa referencia. v.miMetodo()

Comment: El problema es que hay un evento de por medio, el botón "CONFIRMAR", y desde la clase madre no sé como "esperar" que el usuario ingrese los datos para invocar el método

Comment: podrías usar algo como lo que describe en esta página
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497236/how-do-i-notify-a-class-component-of-an-event

Comment: revisa que es encapsulamiento, lo que puedes hacer y lo que te recomiendo es en la clase hija crear una instancia de la clase padre, por ejemplo: el frame principal es: FRM_PRINCIPAL, y en la clase hija donde tu quieres gestionar los datos crear una instancia que de la clase padre como: FRM_PRINCIPAL frmPrincipal. y en la case hija crear los get y set correspondientes de ese frm... cualdo tu pulsas sobre el boton confirmar creas una instancia del frm hijo, en el cual tendiras que pasar el objeto padre para poder procesarlo alli.. por ejemplo seria

Comment: FrmHija frmHija=new FrmHija();           
frmHija.setFrmPadre(this);          
frmHija.setVisible(true);

Comment: luego podrias acceder a los metodos get y set que tengas en tu clase padre. nose si me doy a entender.